# Magento - Add to cart error

Tags: magento, error

I have set-up a Magento cart system and got everything working the way i want, but somehow in the process this error has came up.

> The address total model should be extended from
>   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract.

This error only comes up when i try to add things to my cart.
Has anyone else encountered this error or know how to fix it?

Comment: What version of magento?

Comment: By "got everything working the way I want", do you mean you've made modifications? If so - what?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by reinstalling the CORE Magento module, I created this problem by editing the core files.

Comment: Never, _ever_, edit core files (unless there's an urgent security issue that can't be fixed any other way and you're absolutely sure the manual patch is safe). There's a reason why these platforms have extensible architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this article:

http://blog.magestore.com/2012/09/07/magento-certificate-total-models/